# Django и сигналы - приоритет значения

Tags: django, form, signal

Доброе время суток.

В проекте набралось много приложений, которые могут перекрывать друг друга - добавлять новый функционал или расширять его совместно с другими. Для базового приложения нужна форма, находящаяся в зависимом от нее приложении. Эти приложения могут быть произвольно включены или отключены.

**UPDATE:** Каждое приложение дополняет форму своими полями, и если вслючено несколько приложений, то будет несколько дополнительных полей

Как реализовать получение нужной формы?

Пока мне пришел в голову только вариант с сигналом

```
# поиск формы в базовом функционале
class X:
    def get_form(self):
        form = FormBase
        get_form_signal.send(sender=self)

# приложение A1 зависит от базовового и не зависит от A2, но имеет приоритет ниже чем A2. Не знает о существовании A2

@receiver(...)
def callback(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.form = FormA1

# Приложение A2, знает что есть приложение A1. A2 - самый высокий приоритет
def callback(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.form = FormA2
```

но тут проблема, что обработчики вызываются как попало, никогда не узнаешь порядок вызова...

В принципе можно было бы мофицировать класс формы через функцию, что, наверное, больше подходит для моего варианта

```
@receiver(...)
def callback(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.form = modify_form_to_A1(sender.form)

# Приложение A2, знает что есть приложение A1. A2 - самый высокий приоритет
def callback(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.form = modify_form_to_A2(sender.form)
```

Но здесь больше обработок, наследований и тп ...

---

Или может стоит написать декоратор класа, который найдет все дополнительные методы из других приложений и использует их в базовой форме в соответсвующих методах ?

Comment: Лично я бы склонялся к чему-то похожему на вариант из последнего предложения, сигналы выглядят как-то костыльно

Comment: Я когда-то пилил главную страницу сайта, состоящую из блоков от независимых приложений. Чтобы базовое приложение получило блоки от зависимых приложений, я завёл специальный модуль, который хранит функции для получения блоков, и приложения регистрируют свои функции в этом модуле, а базовое приложение потом читает всё из этого модуля: https://pastebin.com/rQ9EeCVS Если несколько приложений попытаются зарегистрировать один и тот же блок, то порядок вызова зависит от порядка в INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Есть ещё вариант прописать путь к нужной форме в настройках `X_FORM_CLASS = 'app2.forms.App2Form'` и дальше импортировать прописанный в настройках класс, а приоритет в таком случае будет выбирать сам админ путём прописывания нужной строки в настройках

Comment: @andreymal для зависимых приложений сигналы - не такое уж и плохое решение, когда надо заменить/обновить небольшой функционал, который должен в писаться в работу базового. Про прописывание в найстройках я подумаю .... ибо возможно это не подойдет из-за уведличения кол-во форм. Форма из A1 имеет 1 доп поле и работает, если нет A2. Форма А2 имеет свое доп поле и поля из других подключенных приложений, вроде А2, то есть поля из A2 и A1. Если A1 отключено, только из A2.