# Django - переопределение View в urls.py

Tags: django, view

Доброе время суток.

Имеется проект со сложным определением URL'ов в urls.py

```
# project/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
  ...
  # Основной функционал
  url(r'path1/', include(base_app.urls.urlpatterns_1),
  url(r'path2/', include(base_app.urls.urlpatterns_2),

  ...
  # Тут что то вроде урлов по всем отчетам из приложений
  url(r'path3/', include([
        url(r'path4/', base_app.urls.urlpatterns_3),
        url(r'path5/', any_app.urls),
  )]
  ...
  # То, что не влияет на базовое приложение
  url(r'other_app_path/', include(other.urls),
  ...
]

# base_app/urls.py

urlpatterns1 = [
  ...
  url(r'page/', include(view1),
  url(r'page2/', include(view2),
  ...
]

urlpatterns2 = [
  ...
]
```

Имеется базовое приложние и часть зависимых от него.

Также появилось приложение, которое частично дополняет, частично переопределяет функции view базового приложения.

Вопрос: Как реализовать, чтобы при подключении зависимого приложения по одному и тому же url подставлялась его view, а не из базового приложения?

Comment: Сделать view, который внутри себя будет выбирать и запускать нужный view по [аналогичному из предыдущего вопроса принципу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/999474/django-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f#comment1690594_999474)?

Comment: ну тоже вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, протестировав несколько пришедших в голову вариантов, нашел один более-менее оптимальный

Надо указать полный url для переопределения в `urls.py` проекта. Если же пытаться переопределить конструкцией из вложенных include, то будет ошибка

Если у url, которые собираемся переопределить, то у переопределяемого он должен отсутсвовать, так как django не нравится, когда имя урла неуникальное.

```
# project/urls.py
from other import urls as other_urls

urlpatterns = [
    ...
]

# Вставляем урлы для переопределения
if apps.is_installed('other'):
    urlpattrens += other_urls.overrided_urls

# Вставляем урлы, которые могут быть перепоределены
urlpattrens += [
  url(r'page/', include(view1),
  url(r'page2/', include(view2),
]
```

```
# other/urls.py

overrided_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'path1/page/', view,), # Важно! name не указываем у переопределяемого url'а 
]
```

Как это работает

Django подставляем url запроса по очереди во все шаблоны url'ов, пока не получит первое совпадение. Так как мы прописали полный url в файле проекта без вложенности, то когда url совпадет, отображится нужная нам view. В противном случае проверка на совпадение пойдет дальше.

Почему не работает со вложенными url. Потому что входя в include, django думает, что довпадение будет где то в этом блоке и прекращает поиск в остальных блоках, что приводит к ошибкам

PS: Если есть варианты как улучшить ответ, оставьте комменты

Answer (score -2):

## base_app/urls.py

```
urlpatterns1 = [

  url(r'page/', views.Название Функции В Файле view.py,name="Любое Имя"),
  url(r'page2/', views.Название Функции В Файле view.py,name="Любое Имя"),

]
```

Comment: Это будут 2 разных URL'a